# cmake prepending part of the build directory into the library path

Tags: cmake, ld

I've got a cmake file that builds a shared library, a binary, and then links them. This seems to work fine, until I go to run it on the target machine. I was expecting that just the library's name would be defined, and the loader would search for the library along the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, however what I see when I run it is different:

```
/bin/my_prog: error while loading shared libraries: builds/debug/lib/my_lib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`src/my_lib/builds/debug/lib` is where the library is stored during the build process (created with externalproject_add), but I don't see why it's seemingly picked a random subset of this directory to use as part of the search path.

I've tried playing with the rpath:

```
set( CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH true )
```

to no avail.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what to try next, as the loader/linker are not my strong suit. What's causing cmake to do this?

## Edit:

The cross compile is simply created by using a different toolchain:

`toolchain=x86_64-silvermont-linux-gnu`

The *relevant* part of the cmake file:

```
add_library(dx1 SHARED
    src/lib/phy.c
    )

ExternalProject_Add(my_lib
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib/sdk 
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" 
    BUILD_COMMAND "make"
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib/sdk
    LOG_BUILD 1 
    LOG_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE 1
    BUILD_ALWAYS)

find_library(MY_LIB
    NAMES my_lib.so.2
    PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib/builds/debug/lib
    #PATH_SUFFIXES lib
    NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
    NO_CMAKE_PATH
    NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH)

target_link_libraries(dx1 ${MY_LIB} rt)

add_executable(unittest_main src/test/main.c)
target_link_libraries(unittest_main dx1)
```

Also important to note that the rt library seems to link just fine:

```
/ # ldd /bin/unittest_main
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee53ed000)
    libdx1.so => /usr/lib64/libdx1.so (0x00007f756ebe1000)
    builds/debug/lib/my_lib.so.2 => not found
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f756ebd7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f756ea1b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f756e9fa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f756ebe8000)
```

This appears to be a specific issue with the library built with externalproject_add

Comment: Use `readelf -d <exe>` and/or `ldd` to determine, if some lib is linked via a relative path. It pretty much looks like the relative path in the build dir remains in the binary. This can happen when building. If you use cmake's `install()` (or cpack for generating a package which internally uses cmake install logic) the rpath or library paths may get adjusted...

Comment: How exactly did you link the shared lib btw? There are some cases where additional info needs to be provided to cmake...

Comment: @fabian Yes, ldd shows all the other libraries are pathed correctly, but this one in particular is not. This is all done via cross-compiling, so no install() step is included (AFAIK, the build does create a rootfs though). The library is linked via `target_link_libraries(binary library)`. Nothing fancy

Comment: Please, add into the **question post** your **code** and the way how do you build it. E.g. cross-compiling is very important. Without the code we could only **guess** what is going on, and this is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Alright, unload the emphasis cannon. I've added the relevant parts of the cmakelists to the question. The code itself has zero relevance to the question. It could well be an empty main and the same result would happen. The question is relevant specifically to the externalproject_add and/or target_link_libraries functions in cmake

Comment: Would you run `readelf -d` for your **library** (`my_lib.so.2`), then it most likely will print `Library soname: [builds/debug/lib/my_lib.so.2]`. Exactly a library's **soname** is embedded by the linker into the executable when you link the executable with the library. So you need to fix your external project to produce correct soname for the library. (Normally a soname contains a **name** of the library file, not a *relative path*.)

Comment: Interesting - I didn't have readelf on the build machine but moving it over to something that does, the soname indeed does include the path. The mistake was changing compilers at the same time as changing to cmake, and blaming cmake instead of the compiler (clang->gcc)